# How to integrate spring web application with ADFS

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, saml-2.0, adfs2.0

I have developed a basic Java spring application which supports SSO with the reference of [this article](https://venkatsadasivam.com/2009/08/29/single-sign-on-in-java-platform/) and its working fine now, without asking login credentials from users.

Now I am looking for configurations to support with SAML 2.0 and with ADFS. I have gone through many articles and videos in YouTube but no use. I have got one setup guide from spring forum with sample application [from here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/). When I deploy the WAR file and navigate to the URL, I get the error like this.

[image: error like this]

I don't know what mistake I made. Please some one tell me about this to resolve. I don't know I have made a mistake in this application or in ADFS. I have attached both the files metadata and securitycontext xml files.

**Metadata.xml :** [file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2VLMydeURXpeHVJRTVUejd3YzA)

**securityContext.xml :** [file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2VLMydeURXpZl9hZXF0V2drc3M)

Can any one tell me the procedure or clear setup guide regarding how to implement ADFS, SAML2.0 configuration with spring.

Comment: Can you please provide securityContext.xml in a way it's accessible?

bean 'metadata' has class 'ResourceBackedMetadataProvider' where you specify the path to the IdP-Meta Data.

In general intergrating ADFS-based SAMLv2 IdP is not different from any other SAMLv2 IdP, except that Microsoft sometimes does not comply with the meta data schema defined in SAMLv2 meta data profile and you may have to adopt the meta data provided by the ADFS admin. Also make sure that really SAMLv2 is used and not WS-Federation with SAML(v1.1) TokenType.

Comment: @bernhard I have attached the file with my question itself... and have solved the issue... it was my mistake I didn't change the .jks file which given in the application with my .jks file to identify the IDP from the Metadata xml file...